# how to run the task in parallel?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, winapi, timer

```
int CreateSocket() 
{




//  SOCKET connectedSocket;
//  SOCKADDR_IN addr;

//  char buf[256];
//  char buf2[300];
  // Winsock starten
    HANDLE h1,h2,h3;

double Task2ms_Raster, Task10ms_Raster, Task100ms_Raster ;
long rc;
 SOCKET acceptSocket;



   rc=startWinsock();
  if(rc!=0)

  {

    printf("Fehler: startWinsock, fehler code: %d\n",rc);

    return 1;

  }

  else

  {

    printf("Winsock gestartet!\n");

  }

  // Socket erstellen

  acceptSocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);

  if(acceptSocket==INVALID_SOCKET)

  {

    printf("Fehler: Der Socket konnte nicht erstellt werden, fehler code: %d\n",WSAGetLastError());

    return 1;

  }

  else

  {

    printf("Socket erstellt!\n");

  }

memset(&addr,0,sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));

addr.sin_family=AF_INET;

addr.sin_port=htons(port);

addr.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(INADDR_ANY);

rc=bind(acceptSocket,(SOCKADDR*)&addr,sizeof(SOCKADDR_IN));

if(rc==SOCKET_ERROR)

{

  printf("Fehler: bind, fehler code: %d\n",WSAGetLastError());

  return 1;

}

else

{

  printf("Socket an port %d gebunden\n",port);

}


rc=listen(acceptSocket,10);

if(rc==SOCKET_ERROR)

{

  printf("Fehler: listen, fehler code: %d\n",WSAGetLastError());

  return 1;

}

else

{

  printf("acceptSocket ist im listen Modus....\n");

}

connectedSocket=accept(acceptSocket,NULL,NULL);

if(connectedSocket==INVALID_SOCKET)

{

  printf("Fehler: accept, fehler code: %d\n",WSAGetLastError());

  return 1;

}

else

{

  printf("Neue Verbindung wurde akzeptiert!\n");

//    strcpy(buf,"Hallo wie gehts?");

//    rc=send(acceptSocket,buf,9,0);

      // Daten austauschen
  while(rc!=SOCKET_ERROR)
  {
    rc=recv(connectedSocket,buf,256,0);
    if(rc==0)
    {
      printf("Server hat die Verbindung getrennt..\n");
      break;
    }
    if(rc==SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
      printf("Fehler: recv, fehler code: %d\n",WSAGetLastError());
      break;
    }
    XcpIp_RxCallback( (uint16) rc, (uint8*) buf, (uint16) port );


 h1=TimerTask(2,TASK1,&Task2ms_Raster);
 h2=TimerTask(10,TASK2,&Task10ms_Raster);
 h3=TimerTask(100,TASK3,&Task100ms_Raster);


  }
}
  closesocket(acceptSocket);
  closesocket(connectedSocket);
  XcpIp_OnTcpCxnClosed((uint16) port );
  WSACleanup();
  return 0;
}
```

The above code is a server code and accepts a connection from the client via the ip address and port number. I am accepting the connection and recieving the data from the client. I want to run the TimerTask in the background, timer task is calling a function called TASK1, TASK2 and TASK3 for every 2ms , 10ms and 100ms. So how to run those function in the background. Please someone help me.

Comment: What do you mean, by `running in the background`? Should the window be invisible in Windows, or do you want 2 threads/processes, that are running simultaneously?

Comment: It should be running parallel with recieving data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make things run in parallel, you can use threads for Multithreading, or forks for multiprocessing.

**Here's an example for multithreading in c:**

```
#include <pthread.h>

void handleClient(SOCKET clientSock)
{
... read and write ...
}

int main()
{
    ... prepare the server ...
    ... listen on socket ...
    for(;;){
        connectedSocket=accept(acceptSocket,NULL,NULL);        
        pthread_t *tid = malloc( sizeof(pthread_t) );   
        pthread_create( &tid, NULL, handleClient, connectSocket );

        ... test, if the server should be killed, and break the loop ...
    }
}
```

Notice, that this is a very minimalistic example. You should also care about "collecting your threads" with `pthread_join( tid, NULL );`, thus you have to store all your `pthread_t`-Variables inside an Array or a linked list.